# Creating an AWS Service Role with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I don't get how to configure role policies with Terraform for AWS.

First things first:

```
$ terraform version
Terraform v0.12.0
+ provider.aws v2.18.0
```

Now I need to create a service role and as far as I understood, first I need to create the role with [aws_iam_role](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role.html) and use [aws_iam_role_policy_attachment](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role_policy_attachment.html) to attach CodeDeploy's AWSCodeDeployRole policy.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "codedeploy_service_role" {
  name = "CodeDeployServiceRole"
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "codedeploy_service_role_policy_attach" {
   role       = "${aws_iam_role.codedeploy_service_role.name}"
   policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSCodeDeployRole"
}
```

But it's not working because the *aws_iam_role* resource doesn't have a mandatory field, "assume_role_policy". And the "assume_role_policy " field only accepts JSON formatted policy fields. I don't understand why I can not create a role without setting policies during the initialization of this role.

Comment: AssumeRole policy document is mandatory. That is by design from AWS. You can always modify that later. This is different from the policies that are attached to the role. AssumeRole policy is used to indicate which service or account can assume this role.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correction as I mis-read your question:

You can create a iam_policy as below:

```
data "aws_iam_policy" "codedeploy_service_policy" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSCodeDeployRole"
}
```

Then in your policy attachment:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "codedeploy_service_role_policy_attach" {
   role       = "${aws_iam_role.codedeploy_service_role.name}"
   policy_arn = "${data.aws_iam_policy.codedeploy_service_policy.arn}"
}
```

AWS iam role with assume role policy (with trust relationship)
** when creating a role in AWS, you MUST provide a trust relationship (the service which this particular role will utilize).

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "codedeploy_service_role" {
  name = "CodeDeployServiceRole"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
   {
     "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
     "Principal": {
       "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
     },
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Sid": ""
   }
 ]
}
EOF
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But what will be the content of permissions.json file? Since, I'm trying to use an aws-managed policy, I expect terraform to attach this managed policy to my role, instead of attaching a policy defined in json file.

Comment: And what about the assume_role_policy field of aws_iam_role ?

Comment: What do u mean? That name can be anything you define.

Comment: I mean, if you look at my question you will see the code block of "aws_iam_role" . As you see, it only has "name" attribute, but also must have an assume_role_policy attribute, according to https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role.html

Comment: So, when creating a role in AWS, you MUST provide a trust relationship (the service which this particular role will utilize). So you need to use a similar assume_role_policy as above.

Comment: can we insert more than one policy? in the same json format

Comment: Can we insert another trust relationship after the role is created by "aws_iam_role". Like I want to add new trust relationship to the existing role